# Death sound to play before reloading scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 1 scene (it is infinity level game)

when the player dies (a collision occurred) the sound does not fully play all of it because it reloads too fast:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
 if (collision.tag != currentColor && collision.tag != "Score")
    {
        playerDeath();
    }
}

private void playerDeath()
{
    SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("Error");
    score = 0;
    // SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Infinity Level");
}
```

I can not understand what I have to do to fix this bug

**Edit:**
The sound is 1sec long

Answer (score 1):

You can change playerDeath() function to a courutine and make a delay like

```
private IEnumerator playerDeath()
{
    SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("Error");
    yield return new WaitWhile (()=> SoundManagerScript.source.isPlaying) 
    score = 0;
    // SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Infinity Level");
}
```

Comment: This does not work =/ the ball never die and yes I am using StartCoroutine(playerDeath());

Comment: Hmm then you can make it just wait how much you want yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);  or yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5f) which does not depend on time scale

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the audiosource gameobject active (don't destroy it) when loading scenes using [DontDestroyOnLoad()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) method

Answer (score 0):

While not sure if this fixes the issue, but would moving the sound into the collision detection work? probably not ...

Another solution might be to work on 'play again' functionality upon death, this will delay the scene change until user interaction, which might give enough time to play the sound. Depending on the idea for the game, this interaction may later change into 'respawn at' [latest checkpoint] [home] [start of level] [start of game] ... or w/e else you can think of.

Lastly you might be able to put the SceneManager.LoadScene on a time delay of 1sec. if nothing else is happening and the user can't do anything during this time anyways (except curse at the screen for dying), that might give the time for the sound to play.

Comment: How could I add SceneManager.LoadScene delay of 1sec?